# how to generate the id of a div dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a (+) sign and a (-) sign. If the user clicks on the + sign than whatever their in the row will automatically get generated the same with new id.

Now when user click on + sign than div id and text box under it will get changed.

Code below for div as follows:

```
<div class="row" id="Div0">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastName0" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Now when user clicks on + sign the new row with text box with new id txtLastName1 will get generated.

Now on click of + sign how do i get new id of textbox and a div with new row.

Div1 and textbox1 will get generated

Comment: You seem to have forgotten half your code. Also, there's no question here, just a problem statement. What is the issue?

Comment: How to  create  dynamic id of a div and the text box id using JavaScript on click on + image

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you should do is, keep the markup you want to generate as a template in your DOM and when user clicks the "Add" button, clone this markup and append to the DOM (to a container div). then update the Id's of the input and divs as needed.

A simply sample would be like

```
<div class="row" id="template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control lname" id="txtLastName"
                  placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>

<button id="btnAdd">+</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Now wire up a click event handler to the Add/+ button. You may use the jQuery `clone()` method.

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnAdd").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var childCount = $("#container").children().length;
        var c = $("#template").clone().show();

        c.attr("id", "Div" + childCount );
        c.find(".lname").attr('id', 'txtLastName' + childCount);
        $("#container").append(c);

    });

});
```

For deleting, you can add a event handler on the delete button and remove the specific div from dom.  jQuery `remove()` method will do it. Use `closest()` and `find` as needed to get the correct div to remove.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/lixekinari/edit?html,js,output) is a working simple jsbin sample for your reference